# One stored procedure to update whole table or individual columns too

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table `userdata` which has these columns:

```
userId
userName
userEmail
userContact
userDob
userAdd
userImage
userPass
```

I am using a stored procedure to select data from this table.

Now I want to update this table with a stored procedure. I am able to update this table with stored procedure but my requirement is in `profile.aspx` I allow user to update all columns with stored procedure. But in other forms I want user to update a few columns only, for example on `setting.aspx` page I allow user to update only `userPass` column.

So I have to make another stored procedure. And I have many tables like this. And I wondered how many stored procedure I have to create to update many tables with different columns.

Can anyone suggest a short way so that I can do this with only one stored procedure per table to update whole table or individual columns, too or any c# code to shorten this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would ***NOT*** recommend trying to create a single stored procedure that can update some or all columns all in one procedure. That'll be one huge, messy, complicated, hard-to-understand and hard-to-maintain procedure! Don't do it - it's not worth it. Either you need x stored procedures for your x update scenarios - or then you use an ORM like Entity Framework to avoid having to write tons of procedures....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`ISNULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms184325.aspx) function in MS SQL Server, which is explained by below statement from MSDN.

> Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.

You can write one stored procedure, which updates all the fields that you want to update in various operations. Call the same procedure from all pages. Then from a page only pass relevant parameters for that page & for the remaining parameters (that are not relevant to that page) pass [`null`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Your stored procedure should be like this

```
UPDATE dbo.userTable SET
userName = ISNull(@userName, userName),
userEmail= ISNull(@userEmail, userEmail),
-- list of all your table fields goes here
WHERE userID = @userID
```

What this will do is, if you pass the parameter; it will update value for that field; and if you pass [`null`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for any field it will update that field with its existing value. So that field will not be affected in the update operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can have single stored proc with multiple `if.. else..` condition to control updation of each single field. Then you can pass them as parameter to control which field to update.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this:
At the front page, you should set the fields not editable that you didn't want to update, but pass the values as parameters to the store-procedure. In store-procedure, you campare the old value of these fields to the correspondding parameters, If not equal, update it, otherwise, do nothing with these fields.

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like this:

```
UPDATE tbl t
   SET t.userName =  CASE WHEN @userName  IS NULL THEN t.userName  ELSE @userName  END
     , t.userEmail = CASE WHEN @userEmail IS NULL THEN t.userEmail ELSE @userEmail END
     ,  ...
   WHERE t.userName = CASE WHEN @WHERE_userName IS NULL THEN t.userName ELSE @WHERE_userName END
     AND ...
```

So if you do not want to update specific field just pass DBNull.Value from the code to the procedure call for that parameter.
Keep in mind that this will work only if you do not intend to update a field with NULL value.
If you need nulls you could then rewrite a little bit the code to make it work with nulls. If you need further help, just put a comment.

Comment: thanks bugartist.. this seems what i was expecting.. let me just try.. and will revert back to you.. really thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get your all data in Datatable for which you need to update.
use datatable.WriteXML method and get in **Stream** object all the string use XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema to get only data.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.WriteXml(stream object ,XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema)
```

Now create procedure which accept Varchar(max) parameter and  pass **Stream** object to the procedure.

After that you are able to use Openxml or get all this thing in XML variable in Sqlserver
get all data in @tablevariable or in #temp table.

[Openxml in sqlserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx)
or 
[For Xml for XMl variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx)

then you will get every thing in one table use that table to update your 
database table base on your primary key ID
like....

SQl qquery is like below

```
Update "Database Table Name"
set .........
from "GetDatafromc#table"
```